# I build apk using command eas build -p android but apk not opening in phone

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo, android-build

I build apk using command eas build -p android but apk not opening in phone

[image]

when i open the app showing this page only. please help!

i tried build command

```
eas build -p android
```

and am expecting android build should run like app properly

Answer (score 1):

This is a [development build](https://docs.expo.dev/development/use-development-builds/). You can still run your app natively on your device by running the command `npx expo start --dev-client`.
If you want to create an APK make sure, in your `eas.json` file, `"developmentClient"` is set to `false`. This will create an APK for your android device.